# IE8 throws long running script error while using Google HeatMap overlay

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8, maps

I am trying to render a heatmap using google maps api v3 which works on all browsers but not in IE. IE 9 takes long time to render but IE8 starts throwing "Stop running this script" alert saying the script is taking too long.

I have placed a simple example below with just 5 clusters and IE8 still throws long running script error. Could you please help me with this issue. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var data = [
            { "lat": "45.284397", "lon": "-126.724372", "count": 10 },
            { "lat": "45.284156", "lon": "-126.724853", "count": 5 },
            { "lat": "45.284450", "lon": "-126.725532", "count": 20 },
            { "lat": "45.284839", "lon": "-126.725875", "count": 34 },
            { "lat": "45.285442", "lon": "-126.726181", "count": 46 }
            ];        
        var usaCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(54.6, -119.2);
        var heatMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('heatMap'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: usaCenter,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ["Traffic", google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var heatMapData = [];
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
        $.each(data, function (index, point) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point["lat"], point["lon"]);
            var heatPoint = {
                location: latLng,
                weight: point["count"]
            };
            heatMapData.push(heatPoint);
            bounds.extend(latLng);
        });

        var heatmapOverLay = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: heatMapData,
            opacity: 0.7
        });
        heatmapOverLay.setMap(heatMap);
    });
</script>


<div id="heatMap" style="width:1600px;height:1600px"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

IE8 makes this warning based on the number of statements and not based on the time the scripts are taking to run. This warning in my opinion is inaccurate.

By default threshold limit for the time-out dialog box is 5,000,000 statements.

Microsoft released a patch to correct this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

Please note that microsoft also indicates that which is the registry entry to increase this to any level if necessary:

- Using a Registry Editor such as `Regedt32.exe`, open this key:

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Styles

  *Note If the Styles key is not present, create a new key that is called Styles.*
- Create a new DWORD value called "**MaxScriptStatements**" under this key, and set the value to the desired number of script statements.

If you are not sure about which value you need to set this to, you can set it to a DWORD value of 0xFFFFFFFF to avoid the dialog box.